# Passing Data between functions

Tags: python, function, pass-by-reference

I have been trying to figure out how to pass data between functions, I'm new to coding. I have tried multiple way to do it, I am struggling to understand how data is passed my code is below. Help would be awesome.

```
x = []
y = []
z = []

def w():   #Welcome greeting the user and asking for their name
    print("Welcome to the BMI Index Calculator.")
    name = input("Enter employee's name or Exit to quit: ")  # Allows the user to input there name as a variable
    if str.isnumeric(name):  # Test as a string
        print("That is not a name.")
        w()
    if name == 'Exit':  # sets the Exit for the program
        print("Exiting program...")
        exit()  # ends program
    else:
        name = x.append(name)

def h():
    height = input("Enter employee's height in inches: ")
    if height == '0':  # sets the Exit for the program
        print("Exiting program...")
        exit()  # ends program
    else:
        height = y.append(height)


def wt():
    weight = input("Enter employee's weight in lbs: ")
    if weight == '0':  # sets the Exit for the program
        print("Exiting program...")
        exit()  # ends program
    else:
        weight = z.append(weight)


def bmi():     #gives the data back to the user
    print(str(x).replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace("'", '') + "'s " + "BMI profile")
    print("---------------------------")
    print("Height: ", str(y).replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace("'", ''), '"')
    print("Weight: ", str(z).replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace("'", ''), "lbs.")


def math_cal():
    bmi_weight = int(z) * 703
    bmi_height = int(y) ** 2
    print("BMI: ", bmi_weight / bmi_height)


def run():
    x = w()
    y = h()
    z = wt()
    xy = bmi()
    xz = math_cal()
    __main__()

run()

__main__()
```

I have been successful in passing the data to other functions but the code fails to see the list as an int. Thus I have found my way here, trying to get ideas of how to rewrite this code in a more efficient manner. I am looking for a way to reference functions to pass data between functions, however I have not been find a clean way to execute that process.

Comment: Please try to detach your  actual question from all the noisy lines of code you have provided. Start from scratch and provide us with a minimal example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: None of your functions actually `return` any values - you should start there if you want to write cleaner code

Comment: You are not passing arguments to any of your functions here (all calls are empty: `bmi()`, `math_cal()` etc.). Instead, you are modifying variables that are global (inside your script).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are to points where values are passed when using functions:

- at the start of the function, with parameters
- at the end of the function, as return value

let us first take a look at the return value:
For example in your h() function, you ask the user for the height. This value is stored in height

```
height = input("Enter employee's height in inches: ")
```

after checking for all the cases you want, you can return one value at the end of the function by using "return":

```
return height
```

the complete function becomes:

```
def h():
   height = input("Enter employee's height in inches: ")
   if height == '0':  # sets the Exit for the program
      print("Exiting program...")
      exit()  # ends program
   return height
```

This means if you call the function h() it will ask for the height and return the value which it obtained. This could be used by you program like this:

```
bmi_height = h()
```

or

```
bmi_height = h()*2
```

if you want to multiply the entered value with 2.

The second part, passing values to a function at the start of the function with parameters:

for example you want to use the height and weight when calculating the BMI, then the function becomes:

```
def bmi(height, weight)
    print("BMI: ", bmi_weight / bmi_height)
```

this function has to be called like this:

```
bmi(170, 85)
```

when entering the values hard-coded or

```
height = 170
weight = 85
bmi(height, weight)
```

when you use variables.